# Best way of creating Cassandra cluster connection using Spring data

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am using the below code to connect with cassandra using spring data. But it's painful to create connection everytime.

```
try {
            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(host).build();
            session = cluster.connect("digitalfootprint");
            CassandraOperations cassandraOps = new CassandraTemplate(session);
            Select usersQuery = QueryBuilder.select(userColumns).from("Users");
            usersQuery.where(QueryBuilder.eq("username", username));
            List<Users> userResult = cassandraOps
                    .select(usersQuery, Users.class);
            userList = userResult;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cluster.close();
        }
```

Is there any way we can have a common static connection or utility kind of stuff. I am using this in web application where lots of CRUD operation will be there. SO it will be painful to repeat the code every where.

Answer (score 2):

Just instantiate appropriate beans at the startup time of your spring web application. An example would be :

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() throws UnknownHostException {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        cluster.setPort(9042);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName("mykeyspace");
        session.setConverter(converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }
}
```

Now Inject or Autowire **CassandraOperations** bean , any time you want